# What are all the steps to transfer ownership of a YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, google-account, google-plus, account-management, google-brand-account

I have a channel for my website that I created with an old Yahoo email address (let's call this "A"). I now want to transfer this to my email (let's call this "B") I'm using for the website (`info@mysite.com`). Both are Google Accounts (the latter is a Google Apps for Business account if that makes a difference).

[According to this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4627568?hl=en-GB) I need to add the alternate account as a manager first. But on my YouTube account settings, there is no option "Add or remove managers".

From a few sources it sounds like you need a Google+ Page linked to A to see this option. I have set one up using account A, but there is still no option to add a manager.

On [this page about linking accounts](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2897336?hl=en-GB), it says I should click "Confirm your name" in my account settings, but that option is not there either. Nor is there "Connect with a Google+ page" in the advanced options.

Where do I go from here? This is so convoluted!

Comment: I've never thought about this, good idea though. I just logged into my YT account and it looks like you click on your logo once you've logged in. Upper right corner; but log in first. Click your logo/icon "Add Account". From there I think you should now be able to "set manager"? Perhaps. If you only have one account, you can't be a manager if it's just you? Try it out and let me know what comes of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it isn't already, make sure your channel is connected to a Brand Account. You can transfer it to a brand account on https://youtube.com/account_transfer_channel, you can create a new Brand Account on https://youtube.com/channel_switcher. `[a]`
2. Add your new Google account as manager.
3. Transfer ownership to the new Google account
4. (optional) revoke managing rights for the old Google account
5. (optional) Transfer the channel from the Brand account to the Google account (again, via account_transfer_channel)

`[a] well, it creates a new channel, but moving your old channel to it will overwrite it.`

Comment: Note that it deletes all of your likes, comments, and replies.